# ¿Cómo guardar atributos en el método crear?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema a la hora de **guardar** información que dependen de otra tabla o formulario, es decir en el formulario **producto** tengo una lista desplegable, la cual trae información de otra tabla llamada **tipoproducto**, la pregunta es ¿Cómo invoco en el *managedbean*  esta información para que me guarde en la base de datos?

Código:

```
public void crear() {

    productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService");
    TblProducto producto = new TblProducto();
    producto.setInCodigo(inCodigo);
    producto.setDblPrecioUnitario(precioUnitario);
    producto.setTblTipoProducto(tbltipoproducto);
    producto.setTblProveedor(tblproveedor);
    producto.setNvNombre(nvNombre);

    TblProducto RTblProducto = productoService.add(producto);

    if (RTblProducto != null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito", "Se ingreso el producto correctamente."));
        listaporducto = productoService.lista();
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Al ingresar el producto."));
    }

}

public class ProductoBean extends GenericBB {

    ProductoService productoService;
    TipoproductoService tipoProductoService;
    ProveedorService proveedorService;
    private int inCodigo;
    private double precioUnitario;
    private int tipoProducto;
    private int proveedor;
    private String nvNombre;
    private TblTipoProducto tbltipoproducto;
    private List<TblProducto> listaporducto;
    private TblProducto producto;
    private List<TblTipoProducto> listatipodeproducto;
    private List<TblProveedor> listaproveedor;
    private TblProveedor tblproveedor;

    public final TblProveedor getTblproveedor() {
        return tblproveedor;
    }

    public final void setTblproveedor(TblProveedor tblproveedor) {
        this.tblproveedor = tblproveedor;
    }

    public ProductoBean() {
        productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService");
        tipoProductoService = (TipoproductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipoproductoService");
        proveedorService = (ProveedorService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "proveedorService");
        listaporducto = productoService.lista();
        listatipodeproducto = tipoProductoService.lista();
        listaproveedor = proveedorService.lista();

    }

    public void crear() {

        productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService");
        TblProducto producto = new TblProducto();
        producto.setInCodigo(inCodigo);
        producto.setDblPrecioUnitario(precioUnitario);
        producto.setTblTipoProducto(tbltipoproducto);
        producto.setTblProveedor(tblproveedor);
        producto.setNvNombre(nvNombre);

        TblProducto RTblProducto = productoService.add(producto);

        if (RTblProducto != null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito", "Se ingreso el producto correctamente."));
            listaporducto = productoService.lista();
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Al ingresar el producto."));
        }

    }

    public void buscar() {

        productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService    ");
        TblProducto producto = new TblProducto();
        producto.setInCodigo(inCodigo);
        productoService.get(producto);

    }

    public void actualizar() {

        productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService    ");
        TblProducto producto = new TblProducto();
        producto.setInCodigo(inCodigo);
        producto.setDblPrecioUnitario(precioUnitario);
        // PENDIENTE
        producto.setTblTipoProducto(null);
        // pendiente
        producto.setTblProveedor(null);
        producto.setNvNombre(nvNombre);
        productoService.update(producto);

        // aca iria el codigo para actualizar
    }

    public void eliminar() {

        productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService  ");
        TblProducto producto = new TblProducto();
        producto.setInCodigo(inCodigo);
        productoService.delete(producto);

    }

    public final int getInCodigo() {
        return inCodigo;
    }

    public final void setInCodigo(int inCodigo) {
        this.inCodigo = inCodigo;
    }

    public final double getPrecioUnitario() {
        return precioUnitario;
    }

    public final void setPrecioUnitario(double precioUnitario) {
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
    }

    public final String getNvNombre() {
        return nvNombre;
    }

    public final void setNvNombre(String nvNombre) {
        this.nvNombre = nvNombre;
    }

    public final List<TblProducto> getListaporducto() {
        return listaporducto;
    }

    public final void setListaporducto(List<TblProducto> listaporducto) {
        this.listaporducto = listaporducto;
    }

    public final TblProducto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public final void setProducto(TblProducto producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public final ProductoService getProductoService() {
        return productoService;
    }

    public final void setProductoService(ProductoService productoService) {
        this.productoService = productoService;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tbltipoproducto
     */
    public TblTipoProducto getTbltipoproducto() {
        return tbltipoproducto;
    }

    /**
     * @param tbltipoproducto
     *            the tbltipoproducto to set
     */
    public void setTbltipoproducto(TblTipoProducto tbltipoproducto) {
        this.tbltipoproducto = tbltipoproducto;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        producto = (TblProducto) event.getObject();

    }

    /**
     * @return the tipoProducto
     */
    public int getTipoProducto() {
        return tipoProducto;
    }

    /**
     * @param tipoProducto
     *            the tipoProducto to set
     */
    public void setTipoProducto(int tipoProducto) {
        this.tipoProducto = tipoProducto;
    }

    /**
     * @return the proveedor
     */
    public int getProveedor() {
        return proveedor;
    }

    /**
     * @param proveedor
     *            the proveedor to set
     */
    public void setProveedor(int proveedor) {
        this.proveedor = proveedor;
    }

    public final TipoproductoService getTipoProductoService() {
        return tipoProductoService;
    }

    public final void setTipoProductoService(TipoproductoService tipoProductoService) {
        this.tipoProductoService = tipoProductoService;
    }

    public final List<TblTipoProducto> getListatipodeproducto() {
        return listatipodeproducto;
    }

    public final void setListatipodeproducto(List<TblTipoProducto> listatipodeproducto) {
        this.listatipodeproducto = listatipodeproducto;
    }

    /**
     * @return the listaproveedor
     */
    public List<TblProveedor> getListaproveedor() {
        return listaproveedor;
    }

    /**
     * @param listaproveedor
     *            the listaproveedor to set
     */
    public void setListaproveedor(List<TblProveedor> listaproveedor) {
        this.listaproveedor = listaproveedor;
    }

    public final ProveedorService getProveedorService() {
        return proveedorService;
    }

    public final void setProveedorService(ProveedorService proveedorService) {
        this.proveedorService = proveedorService;
    }

}
```

[image: formulario producto]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es tu managed bean de JSF y cuál es la clase donde defines la operación `crear`? ¿Cómo se asocian estas clases a nivel de código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que seria mas facil si primero generas tu .xhtml y defines bien tu estructura entre objetos

Algo como esto:

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="Precio Unitario"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{productoBean.producto.precioUnitario}"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="Tipo de producto"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{productoBean.producto.tipoProductoSeleccionado}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione tipo de producto" itemValue=""   noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{productoBean.producto.tiposDeProducto}" var="c" itemValue="#{c.id}" itemLabel="#{c.tipoProducto}"/>                  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

En donde productoBean es el nombre del bean, producto es la propiedad dentro del bean y tipoProducto es una propiedad del producto mismo al igual que precio unitario y toda las demas propiedades

```
public class Producto{
   private Double precioUnitario;
   private List<CatalogoTipoProducto> tiposDeProducto; 
   private int tipoProductoSeleccionado;   
   //getters y setters
}

public CatalogoTipoProducto{
   private Long id;
   private String tipoProducto;
   //getters y setters
}
```

El Manage bean seria algo como esto

```
@ManagedBean(name = "productoBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ProductoBean{
    //Si tu servicio es un ejb pruebes inyectatlo con la anotacion
    //@EJB
    private ServicioProducto servicioProducto;
    private Producto producto; 

    //getters y setters

    @PostConstruct
    public void iniciar(){
        //Aqui iria toda la lógica que quieres que se ejecute antes de que    tu bean se //cree, aqui sugiero que llenes tu select, tal vez con una llamada a    un servicio //que leea el catalofo

    producto.setTiposProducto(servicio.leeCatalogoTipoProductos); //En este punto //ya tienes el catalogo para presentarlo en pantalla asignada a la variable //producto.tiposProducto
    }
    public void crearProducto(){
        //Solo le pasas la referencia del objeto producto que esta casado en tu .xhtml
        servicioProducto.crear(producto);
    }
```

}

Y ya en el servicio puedes hacer una interfaz y una clase que la implementa similar a:

```
public interface ServicioProducto(){
   public void crear(Producto producto);
}

public class ProductoImplementacion() implements ServicioProducto{
   public void crear(Producto producto){
     //Logica para guardar en bd 
   }
}
```

Asi te evitarias el estar recuperando los valores de la siguiente manera:

```
productoService = (ProductoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "productoService");
```

y solo manejas objetos, en este caso solo manejas el objeto `producto` y dentro de este objeto haces relaciones del tipo **tiene un** que se refiere al principio composicion de OO, es decir un producto tiene un Tipo de Producto y un producto tiene un precio unitario

Saludos